# Привязка PHP скрипта к "машине"

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, понимаю что вопрос звучит как извращение, но всё таки я должен его задать. Можно ли и как привязать скрипт к определенному компьютеру. Допустим, скрипт установлен на локалхосте и при копировании на другой комп чтобы он не работал. Как ни будь привязать модели платы, серийному номеру HDD или ещё что то ...
У кого какие идеи

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? Ведь код на `php` можно изменить в любом текстовом редакторе...

Comment: об этом я и не подумал как то .... а какие есть решения ?

Comment: Ну, php-файл можно и закодировать, благо есть коммерческие энкодеры. Другое дело, на каждый энкодер есть свой декодер, хотя количество любозначтельных это всё же сократит.

Comment: Ну и самый главный вопрос. Зачем вам это надо?

Comment: так для общих целей

Comment: Если захотите защитить свою интеллектуальную собственность, имейте в виду, что *GTA 4* потратила 200k$ на защиту, которую сломали за один день.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сложно. Но, в теории, можно. Например:
Получаем IP средствами PHP, затем: 
$d=passthru("cat /proc/net/arp");

полученное

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.16.141    0x1         0x2         00:0f:e2:23:21:1f     *        eth0
```

парсим на предмет MAC-адреса (HW address) и не позволяем дальше работать, если не совпадает с записанным в скрипте.

Comment: а нас запускают в докере (сейчас так можно...) и все...

Comment: ну, тогда только писать самому PHP-расширение, которое будет собирать низкоуровневые данные, не переопределяемые докером. Но овчинка не стоит выделки.

Comment: Кстати, подумалось: наличие нестандартного расширения и его использование в скрипте уже, само по себе, немного защищает от тупого копирования. Если оно не установлено, скрипт не сработает.

Comment: главное, что бы в этом расширении была какая то ключевая функциональность.

Comment: Разумеется, иначе это будет защитой лишь от очень примитивного "хакера" :)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть 2 продукта: [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) и [zendguard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads), которые позволяют шифровать код и запускать его там, где есть ключ (ключ может быть привязан к железу). Но старые версии, насколько я помню, удавалось вскрыть и написать декодеры